# Mysql table structure design for economic data

Tags: mysql, database-design, database-normalization

[image]

Dear all Mysql experts 
I am very new for Mysql, please providing me some guides here. I have data as shown in picture above, and I am trying to design table structure of Mysql to store those data and the data will be added over the years, which i dont want to record same indicator multiple times. at the moment i was thinking about split the data into 3 tables: indicator table to hole indicator name, data value table to hold data value and year and the geography table to hold provinces but i am not quite sure if that approach is right please giving me some shade of light. Thank you very much.

Comment: What about categories and data sources? Can you have the same metric, but different data source / category depending on year or geography?

Comment: @Shadow Thanks for helping editing the Tags, the data source and category is not consider as important elements / only year and geography do, and they are not depending on each other

Comment: If these fields are not important, then do you leave them out of your data model? If you inlude them in your data model, then you need to answer the question about them regardless of their importance.

Comment: Hmm yes I might be wrong, at first i was focus too much on the year and geography as they are main element of the data, and yes all field on the table above will be included in the model can you giving some ideas pls

Comment: Right now you are just asking for us to rewrite a textbook with a bespoke tutorial & do your (home)work & you have shown no research or other effort. See [ask], hits googling 'stackexchange homework' & the voting arrow mouseover texts. Show the steps of your work following a design method with justification & ask 1 specific researched non-duplicate question re the first place you are stuck. Time to follow a published academic textbook on information modelling, the relational model & DB design & querying. (Manuals for languages & tools & wiki articles or web posts are not such textbooks.)

Comment: Please [use text, not images/links, for text--including tables & ERDs](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097). Use images only for what cannot be expressed as text or to augment text. Include a legend/key & explanation with an image.

Comment: @amprie286 no, I can't give you ideas because I do not fully understand your data and your needs.

Comment: While 'that approach' may not be right, it may in fact be a step in the right direction. So start with that and then get back to us.

Comment: One tip:  Do not spray an array of things across columns.  I am thinking of your "provinceN" columns.  Unpivot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because its a simple question that deserves a simple answer, here is a suggestion. As per the comments, the sample data you have given is ambiguous, but with assumptions this is it.

From your data, it looks like Indicator, Category and Source are all attributes of the same entity. It also looks like there are an arbitrary number of provinces. If so then you are likely to have three tables

```
Indicator(IndicatorID,IndicatorText,Category,Source)
Province(ProvinceID,ProvinceName)
YearValue(IndicatorID,ProvinceID,Year,Value)
```

You would probably not store the national value, just add up the provinces.

Comment: Yes this is what i was looking for, at first i created 4 tables: indicator(indicator_id, indicatorText, category) datasource(source_id, source_name, year) province(province_id,province_name) datavalue(indicator_id,province_id,source_id,value) what would be the disadvantages of this, thank you very much

Comment: As I said in my assumptions - your sample data only has one source and category per indicator, suggesting they are related. If not, then normalisation rules apply and datasource and category would be broken out into other tables.